# Take a picture with camera, but do not save it

Tags: android, camera, store, send

I want to make a program that takes a picture, geo tag it and store it on my server.

1) Is there a way to take the picture but not save it?  i only want to take the picture, compress it and send it to my server.  i don't want to store it to an sd card or internal storage or anything, just send it.  if this is not possible, then how can i store it temporarily and delete?
2) also, how do i access the picture i just took an to send it?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I don't think there is a way to not save a picture on the phone.  It needs to be kept somewhere, and the other option, application memory, would certainly create many opportunities for OOM errors.

For your second, you can create your camera intent like this:

```
Intent takePictureFromCameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureFromCameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(someFilePathString)));
startActivityForResult(takePictureFromCameraIntent, CAMERA_REQ);
```

This will cause the picture taken by the camera activity to be stored at the path specified by `someFilePathString.` Then, in your `onActivityResult` (or wherever), you can use: `File myFile = new File(someFilePathString)` to access your image to send to your server.

Comment: for someFilePathString, what should i put for the path?  what is a good valid file path for camera images?  also how can i get the name of the image in that directory and how can i delete the image after i've finished my operations?  there does not seem to be anything online or in the dev guides on the andorid dev page about this

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html  Here's a link developer guide that talks about data storage.  You'll probably want a file path to the SD card, but you'll need to check if one is mounted first, else use a path to internal storage.  ( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFilePath() and myContext.getFilesDir() ).  I'm sure you can Google to find a way to create a valid path.  As for deletion, look into some of the methods in the File class, like delete().  It will be much easier to help if you try yourself and post code and more specific issues.